# Magento - Manage stock for bundled products

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a lot of simple products and some bundled products. I want to manage stock for this bundled products. 
I mean, once some products got bundled, I can't 'unbundle' them, so I'll have stock management for this bundled products too.

Is there any way of doing so (natively)? Any extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i can suggest you one the good paid extension to manage your inventory with bundle as well as configurable product.

you can check on his docuement for [Stock inventory](http://amasty.com/custom-stock-status.html)

and you can also check for demo, but before buy please read all functionality which would you require to manage your stock.if it is use full to you  you can sure go for this.

let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: I've abandoned this approach, now I'm solving my problem with simple products and changing the common behavior of "related products". pretty tricky but works :D Thanks anyway